# jQuery for loop with array (Count array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have below function:

```
$(".import-shipments").on("click", function(){
        var sendinger = $('#shipments').val().split("/\n/");

        for(var i = 0; i < sendinger.length; i++){
                    console.log(sendinger[i]); //This returns 3 lines
                    addRow(i,"#rows") //It only adds 1 line
        }

});
```

Which takes the values in my textarea, and count each value per line.

I then have below function, which *should* append a new "row", for each value:

```
  function addRow(id, element){

            var row = '<div class="row">'+
                      '<div>#'+id+'</div>'
                      '</div>';

                     $(element).append(row);

  }
```

The problem is, that above only appends **one** row, when it should append **3**.

Please see this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zf0onzu5/1/) for an example on how above works.

What I want to do is, for each line in the text area, it should also run the `addRow()` function for each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong argument in split function. You are mixing regex and string here. which returns only one element in seninger array. it should be:

```
 var sendinger = $('#shipments').val().split(/\n/); //USING Regex
```

or

```
 var sendinger = $('#shipments').val().split("\n"); //USING String
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mdqkL3fs/)**

Comment: or `.split(/\n/)`

Comment: was updating that only :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!!